# Haskell closes connection before reading the data

Tags: haskell

I wrote the following program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import Control.Exception (bracket)
import Control.Monad (forM)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO(liftIO))
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)
import qualified Database.MongoDB as M

import qualified Data.Text as T

db :: M.Action IO a -> IO a
db action = do
    pipe <- M.connect (M.host "127.0.0.1")
    res <- M.access pipe M.master "haskell" action
    M.close pipe
    return res

main = do
    let docs = (flip map) [0..199999] $ \i ->
            ["name" M.=: (T.pack $ "name " ++ (show i))]
    ids <- forM (chunksOf 50000 docs) $ \chunk ->
      db $ M.insertAll "bigCollection" chunk

    cur <- db $ M.find $ (M.select [] "bigCollection") {M.limit = 100000, M.batchSize = 100000}
    returnedDocs <- db $ drainCursor cur

    putStrLn $ show $ length returnedDocs

drainCursor :: M.Cursor -> M.Action IO [M.Document]
drainCursor !cur = drainCursor' cur []
  where
    drainCursor' cur res  = do
      batch <- M.nextBatch cur
      if null batch
        then return res
        else drainCursor' cur (res ++ batch)
```

After it inserts all the data it becomes stuck on waiting data from the server. I presume it happens because it closes the connection before reading the data. I tried BangPatterns and seq function, bracket function, but no success. It works only if I keep the connection open(by commenting out M.close). Can someone recommend how I can circumvent this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, but it seems you want to open a cursor in the DB, close the connection to the DB, and then continue fetching data from the cursor. If so, how could it possibly work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @chi's comment, you probably want to replace

```
cur <- db $ M.find $ (M.select [] "bigCollection")
                     {M.limit = 100000, M.batchSize = 100000}
returnedDocs <- db $ drainCursor cur
```

by

```
returnedDocs <- db $ do
    cur <- M.find $ (M.select [] "bigCollection")
                    {M.limit = 100000, M.batchSize = 100000}
    drainCursor cur
```

I've never used mongoDB, but I'm quite sure that a database cursor is only usable within the connection in which it was created.

Comment: This helped. I originally solved it by putting putStrLn under db as well. Actually mongodb cursors exist even if we close the original connection. The issue turned out to be that when we receive a cursor it has a postponed IO action in it for reading the first batch. When I start draining the cursor it starts executing this action, but by the time I start executing the action the pipe is already closed. So, this behavior is an artifact of mongodb driver for Mongo. Thanks guys!!!